# PHP EasyRDF : unable to get graph from construct query

Tags: sparql, virtuoso, fuseki, easyrdf

I'm trying to get a `EasyRdf_Graph` object from a query sent via `EasyRdf_Sparql_Client::query`.

[EasyRDF doc says](http://www.easyrdf.org/docs/api/EasyRdf_Sparql_Client.html#method_query):

> `SELECT` and `ASK` queries will return an object of type `EasyRdfSparqlResult`.
>
> `CONSTRUCT` and `DESCRIBE` queries will return an object of type `EasyRdf_Graph`.

Here is my code :

```
<?php
require APPPATH .'third_party/vendor/autoload.php';        
$endpointUrl = "http://data.bnf.fr/sparql";        
$dummyConstructQueryString = "construct { ?s ?q ?r } where { ?s ?p ?o . ?o ?q ?r } limit 1";        
$endPoint = new EasyRdf_Sparql_Client($endpointUrl);
$result = $endPoint->query($dummyConstructQueryString);                
var_dump($result);
echo $result;
?>
```

And here is the output, which is `EasyRdf_Sparql_Result` as you can see :

```
object(**EasyRdf_Sparql_Result**)#47 (6) {
  ["type":"EasyRdf_Sparql_Result":private]=>
  string(8) "bindings"
  ["boolean":"EasyRdf_Sparql_Result":private]=>
  NULL
  ["ordered":"EasyRdf_Sparql_Result":private]=>
  NULL
  ["distinct":"EasyRdf_Sparql_Result":private]=>
  NULL
  ["fields":"EasyRdf_Sparql_Result":private]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "s"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "p"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "o"
  }
  ["storage":"ArrayIterator":private]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#48 (3) {
      ["s"]=>
      object(EasyRdf_Resource)#49 (2) {
        ["uri":protected]=>
        string(56) "http://www.w3.org/ns/sparql-service-description#endpoint"
        ["graph":protected]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["p"]=>
      object(EasyRdf_Resource)#50 (2) {
        ["uri":protected]=>
        string(47) "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type"
        ["graph":protected]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["o"]=>
      object(EasyRdf_Resource)#51 (2) {
        ["uri":protected]=>
        string(42) "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class"
        ["graph":protected]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
  }
}
+-------------+----------+------------+
| ?s          | ?p       | ?o         |
+-------------+----------+------------+
| sd:endpoint | rdf:type | rdfs:Class |
```

Also tried with different endpoints (http://dbpedia.org/sparql and <del>http://localhost:3030/testFuseki</del>) because I saw this issue : https://github.com/njh/easyrdf/issues/226, but it's the same.

**Infos about install**

- EasyRDF version 0.9.1 installed with Composer
- PHP Version 7.0.30-0+deb9u1 + Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)

Any clue would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**

Actually **it works with my local install of Fuseki**. Since http://data.bnf/fr/sparql and http://dbpedia.org/sparql are both Virtuoso endpoints, I wonder if the problem is only with Virtuoso.

Comment: I'm wondering why you're asking here, instead of raising an [EasyRDF issue](https://github.com/njh/easyrdf/issues), as this does appear to be EasyRDF-specific... I do note that there doesn't seem to have been a proper [version 0.9.1 release](https://github.com/njh/easyrdf/releases) (only [a 0.9.1 tag](https://github.com/njh/easyrdf/tags)), and there have been [100+ commits since](https://github.com/njh/easyrdf/compare/0.9.1...master), including the fix for the issue 226 you flagged, so you might want to rebuild your own from [the current codebase](https://github.com/njh/easyrdf).

Comment: Hi Ted, thanks a lot for your help. 1) "there doesn't seem to have been a proper version 0.9.1 release (only a 0.9.1 tag)," : I wasn't aware of that. I installed EasyRDF recently, with composer, as explained here : http://www.easyrdf.org/docs/getting-started . 2) "so you might want to rebuild your own from the current codebase" : I tried to install but didn't find how to include the library ; so I also tried this method https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/easyrdf/_L6qJVtn-ek/FFbccscPBwAJ with stable version 0.9.0 ; but the problem is still the same. How can I rebuild from the current code?

Comment: @TallTed 
"I'm wondering why you're asking here, instead of raising an EasyRDF issue" : I was not sure if it was an issue, and I thought the problem had been solved since 2015. Do you think I should close this topic and ask on groups.google or Github?

Comment: _Please note that edits to your question do not result in alerts to participants._ I see that you now say that your test works against your local Fuseki (which was initially reported to fail), but not against the Virtuoso endpoints you tried (DBpedia, BnF). Based on that info, I have an idea what may be happening. Confirmation requires the full HTTP headers of the SPARQL query being sent from EasyRDF, and optimally the full HTTP headers of the response EasyRDF receives from Virtuoso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ted's suggestion about the headers and updating EasyRDF, I found [a solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/easyrdf/kQzZoL8CmAc) after reading a bit more about EasyRDF issue #226. The problem is that it requires to re-write php code to use the new namespaces, etc. If anyone knows a solution with 0.9.1 version, it would be very helpful!

It seems that the returned object type (`EasyRdf_Graph` / `EasyRdf_Sparql_Result`) depends on the `Accept` parameter of the headers. I tried to modify it (added different content-types listed in [Virtuoso doc](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VOSSparqlProtocol)  ) via Firebug and re-send the request, but didn't get any `EasyRdf_Graph` object yet with Virtuoso.

---

As Ted asked, here is the relevant part of request headers (with above php code and EasyRDF 0.0.1) :

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

In order to get the endpoint response headers, I added this line :

```
print_r(get_headers($endpointUrl));
```

Here are the response headers for Fuseki (which gives an `EasyRdf_Graph` object) :

```
[0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[1] => Date: Tue, 11 Sep 2018 06:14:56 GMT
[2] => Fuseki-Request-ID: 13
[3] => Vary: Accept,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Charset
[4] => Content-Type: application/n-quads
[5] => Vary: User-Agent
```

And for Virtuoso (http://data.bnf.fr)

```
[0] => HTTP/1.1 302 Found
[1] => Date: Tue, 11 Sep 2018 06:12:29 GMT
[2] => Server: Apache
[3] => Location: http://data.bnf.fr/sparql/
[4] => Content-Length: 210
[5] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
[6] => Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
[7] => Connection: close
[8] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[9] => Date: Tue, 11 Sep 2018 06:12:29 GMT
[10] => Server: Apache
[11] => Last-Modified: Mon, 19 Feb 2018 10:34:21 GMT
[12] => ETag: "200036-3a99-5658e3ca8a540"
[13] => Accept-Ranges: bytes
[14] => Content-Length: 15001
[15] => Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
[16] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
[17] => Content-Type: text/html
[18] => Content-Language: fr
[19] => Connection: close
```

N.B. : for data.bnf.fr the code is 302 (redirection), but it doesn't seem to make any difference, see dbpedia response :

```
[0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[1] => Date: Tue, 11 Sep 2018 07:17:23 GMT
[2] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
[3] => Content-Length: 14172
[4] => Connection: close
[5] => Vary: Accept-Encoding
[6] => Server: Virtuoso/07.20.3229 (Linux) i686-generic-linux-glibc25-64  VDB
[7] => Expires: Tue, 18 Sep 2018 07:17:23 GMT
[8] => Cache-Control: max-age=604800
[9] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
[10] => Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
[11] => Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
[12] => Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Accept-Encoding
[13] => Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

---

So here is the **solution with new php code and composer update** to get EasyRDF dev-master :

1) Edit composer.json :

```
{
    "require": {
        "easyrdf/easyrdf": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

2) run

```
php composer.phar update
```

3) rewrite php code :

```
require_once './third_party/vendor/autoload.php';
$endpointUrl = "http://data.bnf.fr/sparql";        
$dummyConstructQueryString = "construct { ?s ?q ?r } where { ?s ?p ?o . ?o ?q ?r } limit 1";        
$endPoint = new \EasyRdf\Sparql\Client($endpointUrl); // <-- here use the namespace
$result = $endPoint->query($dummyConstructQueryString);                
var_dump($result);
```

---

**EDIT**

Finally I'm not sure that the http request headers parameter "Accept" is the condition to get an `EasyRdf_Graph` object. Here are the headers for request and response with updated Easyrdf code ("dev-master" version). Maybe EasyRDF parses the query and the result to build a `EasyRdf_Graph` object.

- Request

  ```
   Host: localhost
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0
   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
   Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
   DNT: 1
   Connection: keep-alive
   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
   Cache-Control: max-age=0
  ```
- Response from http://data.bnf.fr/sparql/ (obtained with `print_r(get_headers($endpointUrl));` )

  ```
   [0] => HTTP/1.1 302 Found
   [1] => Date: Wed, 12 Sep 2018 06:21:48 GMT
   [2] => Server: Apache
   [3] => Location: http://data.bnf.fr/sparql/
   [4] => Content-Length: 210
   [5] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
   [6] => Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
   [7] => Connection: close
   [8] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   [9] => Date: Wed, 12 Sep 2018 06:21:48 GMT
   [10] => Server: Apache
   [11] => Last-Modified: Mon, 19 Feb 2018 10:34:21 GMT
   [12] => ETag: "200036-3a99-5658e3ca8a540"
   [13] => Accept-Ranges: bytes
   [14] => Content-Length: 15001
   [15] => Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
   [16] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
   [17] => Content-Type: text/html
   [18] => Content-Language: fr
   [19] => Connection: close
  ```

Comment: The endpoint URL in `And for Virtuoso (http://data.bnf.fr)` should be `http://data.bnf.fr/sparql`. That will change the `302` to a `200` and probably get the response headers I was looking for from that server ... which are in the output from the DBpedia endpoint.

Comment: @TallTed : Actually it's a typo in my explanation, but the php code has the good url (see also response headers).

Comment: Your "maybe EasyRDF parses..." guess is baseless. Fuseki cannot return any of the specific MIME types requested by EasyRDF, so it returns it's "natural" MIME type for the `CONSTRUCT` query, `application/n-quads`. Virtuoso *can* return the specific MIME types requested by EasyRDF, so it does as requested -- but EasyRDF then does not (or possibly cannot) transform the `text/html` to an `EasyRdf_Graph` object. This is neither a strength in Fuseki nor a weakness in Virtuoso; it's a lucky (for you) alignment of EasyRDF and Fuseki behaviors.

Comment: @TallTed : "Your "maybe EasyRDF parses..." guess is baseless". : not _totally_ baseless, I read this : " Our result-type detector is sub-optimal. It could initiate heuristical analysis of data when default parser failed " (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/easyrdf/kQzZoL8CmAc).

Comment: That comment in the google-group basically says that when EasyRDF's parser finds that the format (the mime-type) of a query response does not match that promised by its `Content-Type:` response header, EasyRDF will try to heuristically determine the actual mime-type of the response, and proceed from there. As both Fuseki and Virtuoso do deliver their response in the form promised by their `Content-Type:` header, these heuristics do not come into play. The problem remains that EasyRDF requests, and Virtuoso delivers, `text/html`. Many if not most other SPARQL endpoints will return the same.

Comment: @TallTed : Ok, my understanding of this comment was different : EasyRDF (0.9.1) parses the query and the response body in order to choose between `EasyRdf_Graph` and `EasyRdf_Sparql_Result` ; if this parsing fails, further (heuristical) analysis should be triggered, which is not the case (in 0.9.1 version). If you're right, I don't understand _how dev-version can return an `EasyRdf_Graph` object, since the request headers is still_ `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0`

Comment: The detail necessary for this conversation is ill-suited to comments on SO. (Also, SO frowns on such back-and-forth.) Suffice to say, EasyRDF asks for `text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml`. Fuseki cannot satisfy any of these, so they satisfy the wildcard fallback ,`*/*`. Virtuoso *can* satisfy these specific requests, and so it does. What EasyRDF does from that point, and the fact that it initially asks for MIME types it does not really want and cannot really handle in this context, is entirely up to EasyRDF to fix.

Comment: Hi Ted. "The detail necessary for this conversation is ill-suited to comments on SO. (Also, SO frowns on such back-and-forth." : yes, that's why I posted a comment here yesterday : https://groups.google.com/d/msg/easyrdf/kQzZoL8CmAc/ZYtlX7idBgAJ . Also tried to use SO chat, when SO "frowned" and proposed a link to chat, but it didn't work. Thanks for your help and your patience.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is revealed by the HTTP request headers emitted by EasyRDF and posted in your answer (all of which additional detail should actually be edited into your question).

The EasyRDF request header --

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

-- says that EasyRDF is equally happy to receive `text/html` or `application/xhtml+xml`, and would then prefer `application/xml`, followed by `*/*` or "any media type".

This is actually not so!  `text/html` is *not* what EasyRDF wants, and it is definitely not just-as-good as `application/xhtml+xml` nor better than `application/xml` in this context.

That said, Virtuoso is doing exactly as requested by EasyRDF, and delivering `text/html` ... which EasyRDF is unsurprisingly not treating as a graph.

You're just getting lucky in what you're getting back from Fuseki (which is `application/n-quads`, which is not any of the specific MIME types requested by EasyRDF)

EasyRDF *should* be requesting some RDF MIME type(s) (such as `text/turtle`, `application/rdf+xml`, `application/trig`, `application/n-triples`, `application/n-quads`, `application/ld+json`, `sparql-results+xml` ... not all of which are actually supported by EasyRDF, so this list should not simply be put into that `Accept:` header).  EasyRDF should also be indicating that these (possibly with an internal preference order) are preferred over any non-RDF MIME types (including all the specific MIME types EasyRDF is currently requesting) or the wildcard (`*/*`).

This should be [reported as a bug in EasyRDF](https://github.com/njh/easyrdf/issues/).  Feel free to tag me ([@TallTed on github](https://github.com/tallted/)) in your report.

Comment: Hi Ted, thanks for your explanations. I'm not sure the problem came from the request headers (see the EDIT in my answer). This being said, do you still advise to **report a bug**? I wonder if it wouldn't be more relevant to ask for **updating install documentation** instead [ warning : don't install 0.9.1 version, download dev-master ; cf this page : http://www.easyrdf.org/docs/getting-started ]

Comment: @ TallTed : "You're just getting lucky in what you're getting back from Fuseki" : I don't think this has anything to do with luck, I assume Fuseki code is smart enough to recognize a `CONSTRUCT` query and send the appropriate content-type.

Comment: @vvffl - Your assumption is baseless. Fuseki cannot return any of the specific MIME types requested by EasyRDF, so it returns it's "natural" MIME type for the `CONSTRUCT` query, `application/n-quads`. Virtuoso *can* return the specific MIME types requested by EasyRDF, so it does as requested -- but EasyRDF then does not (or possibly cannot) transform the `text/html` to an `EasyRdf_Graph` object. This is neither a strength in Fuseki nor a weakness in Virtuoso; it's a lucky (for you) alignment of EasyRDF and Fuseki behaviors.

Comment: Sorry Ted, I was trying to make a joke, meaning "luck doesn't exist, there's always a reason and I'd like to know it". I see you're a "Virtuoso evangelist", and didn't want to say that fuseki is smarter than Virtuoso. Ok, let's say I'm lucky if you define "luck" as "a good alignment for my goal". So the "rational" reason is "Fuseki has a natural mime-type for construct queries which is application/n-quads", thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Well... "(Current) Fuseki has a default mime-type for construct queries (`application/n-quads`) which is delivered here because (current) Fuseki cannot satisfy any of EasyRDF's specifically requested mime-types."  Virtuoso's default `CONSTRUCT` mime-type, returned for queries which do not request a specific mime-type, is `text/turtle`. See here: `curl -LI "http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=construct+%7B+%3Fs+%3Fq+%3Fr+%7D+where+%7B+%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo+.+%3Fo+%3Fq+%3Fr+%7D+limit+1&format=auto&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&run=+Run+Query+"`.

Comment: I would not advise relying on Fuseki continuing to be unable to satisfy the specifically requested mime-types.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I assume that even if we can get an `EasyRdf_Graph` object with dev-master version, this should be reported to EasyRDF team. N.B. :  `EasyRdf_Graph` object is important because it has serialization methods etc, which `EasyRdf_Sparql_Result` doesn't provide.

Comment: EasyRDF produces `EasyRdf_Graph` or `EasyRdf_Sparql_Result` based on what it gets back from the SPARQL endpoint, which is determined by (1) what EasyRDF requests (`text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0`) and (2) what the SPARQL endpoint is capable of delivering. EasyRDF's request *should* prefer RDF serializations over the generic and non-RDF `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9`, as that is what EasyRDF really wants, and what SPARQL endpoints are more likely able to deliver.